# How to fix it i got and error 'Scheme is not a constructor'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

i want to create one input text and save the result to separated fields on mongoDb. i got an error 'Scheme is not a constructor' how to fix it

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const profileSchema = mongoose.Schema;

const Scheme = new profileSchema({
        fullName:String,
        age:Number,
        address:String    
});

dataSchema = new Scheme({
    data : {
        type: Scheme,
        required: true
    }
});

var Profile = mongoose.model('Profile', dataSchema);

var profile = new Profile();
var error = profile.validateSync();
assert.ok(error.errors['data']);
```

Comment: `Scheme != Schema` - You have a typo. Also `type: Schema` ( with the correction ) makes no sense. You probably should read the [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) some more before continuing.

Comment: i want to make a nested object with declaration Sceme on new profileSchema , and dataSchema on new Scheme.

Comment: Instead do `const profileSchema = new Schema({ ... })` and then `const dataSchema = new Schema({ data: profileSchema })` like that. The `Schema` is the actual thing with the constructor. Again the link I just gave you explains "Schema" in great detail. Either embedded or referenced and Objects or arrays. Your mistake says to me you need to spend more time reading the documentation and trying the examples before implementing your own code. When you understand it better, then you can do what you want with ease.

Comment: Of course the `...` here is just a placeholder for the actual definition of fields you want in there. Don't just type `...`

Comment: thankyou , i just new with this kind of stuffs